# Covering lattice with circles

Tags: circles, integer-lattices

There is a $m \times n$ lattice and some circles are covering the vertices on it. (The one that's covering the edges is it's boundary not the inside of the circle) How many circles do we need to cover all the edges in the lattice? (I'm sorry I'm not so good at English but I hope you guys understood what I meant to say) I want to ask if there are some ideas or researches done on this subject or some keywords for searching.

Comment: Your question hasn't enough information : 1) What are the radii of these circles (are all radii the same ?) ? 2) What do you mean by "The one that's covering the edges is it's boundary not the inside of the circle" ? 3) Is your lattice a rectangle divided into squares, say with integer coordinates ?

Comment: I have taken the liberty to erase the "covering-spaces" tag dealing which a much more evolved subject

Comment: The lattice is with integer coordinates and the radius can be any real number. And I meant that (x-a)^2+(y-b)^2=r^2 kind of circles covers the integer coordinate points not (x-a)^2+(y-b)^2<=r^2 these ones

Comment: If $r$ is the common value of the radii, you are looking for a description of the (decreasing by steps) function $f$ where $f(r)=$ minimal number of **closed** disks that are necessary to cover the "lattice". Is it that ? Besides, by "lattice" do you mean only its points (vertices), not including line segments connecting neighbour points ?

Comment: Oh sorry I meant the vertices and the radius does not have to be the same length

Comment: I insist on function $f$. If you have 4 points (the vertices of a square say $(0,0),(1,0),(1,1),(0,1)$). If the common radius $r$ is too small you need $f(r)=4$ disks to cover the 4 points. If $r$ is large, you need only one ($f(r)=1$), and if, say $\tfrac12 < r < \tfrac{\sqrt{2}}{2}$ you need f(r)=2 disks. Therefore, $f$ is a decreasing function, constant by intervals.